# Getting Windows 8.1 on a Chuwi

Tags: windows-tabletpc

I am having a huge issue with my Chui Vi10 I recently updated to the windows 10. Before the upgrade I was not having any issues, now um I am not able to get on the windows part at all. It comes on then goes to the windows logo, then says rebooting to the previous version, then pops up with a flash of a bios screen or something then turns off and does the same thing over and over and over again. GRRRR. I have put on a flash drive the windows 8.1 x32, but I can not figure out how to get it to read the USB. Please someone help. I have down loaded the double drivers from here, but still lost on what the heck to do. Can someone please give me some assistance. Thank you for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

During reboot, hold down the silver volume key and the screen should show both icon - android and windows.

The flashing icon is the mode your machine is in (or is trying to be in).  Use the arrow keys (maybe touch screen too) to lock on to the system you want, then press the silver power key once and you should open up.

Worked for me...